# How can I decide thic cookies problem in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I ran into such a problem.
When I run the application on my laptop (Linux/Ubuntu 18) in the developer console in the Chrome browser, I have this message

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at
>   http://pubsub.rtschannel.com/ was set without the `SameSite`
>   attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with
>   cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.
>   You can review cookies in developer tools under
>   Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

[image]

On another laptop (Linux/Ubuntu 16) in the Chrome browser, when the application is launched locally, there is no such message.

I tried to find at least some information on this subject, but alas I couldn’t. The only thing I could find was the link inside the message that it was a browser bug and in Chrome version number 80 it should be fixed and this setting would be added by default.

Please tell me, does it depend on the browser settings, or can I somehow influence this message programmatically? Can I clean it somehow?
On the project, I use **angularjs** if this can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These warnings are purely informational at the moment and do not affect site functionality. This behaviour will not be enforced until Chrome 80 which is due to  hit stable in Feb 2020.

You can simply turn off the messages by setting `chrome://flags/#cookie-deprecation-messages` to `Disabled`. However, that is purely affecting the display of the messages.

If the `pubsub.rtschannel.com` is not your domain, e.g. it's a third-party service you use, then it's that domain that will be responsible for updating the cookies.

If it is your domain, then you need to review the cookie usage and set an appropriate value for the `SameSite` attribute on the cookie. You can find more context and guidance on https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained.